Is there that can I create a virtual disk image out of my old laptop hard drive?
I have an old 2TB laptop hard drive from my old HP 15-da0061cl notebook. The notebook suffered from internal screen damage as well as the case breaking down due to fall damage. Due to my warranty being expired, I could not replace my old machine so I ended up selling it off to eBay for parts. I was able to remove my hard drive before I sold the rest of the notebook.
I wanting to a create an image copy of the of hard drive. I asked around was told that it might not be possible due to the hardware no longer being there anymore. I still wanted to somehow create an image copy to convert into a virtual machine for VMWare or VirtualBox to use.  It had a Windows 10 x64 OS before I sold off the notebook hardware that it was in. How can I create an image from that old hard drive? Or am I better off just copying the files and moving on?

is the hard drive encrypted?

VMware has a product that converts a physical HDD to a VHDD have you tried that product? All it requires is a Windows install and access to the hdd. Trivial to purchase a 2.5 HDD to USB adapter

You might also consider creating a virtual machine which uses your actual HDD instead of creating a copy of the HDD.

What is the name of the product? And how do you create a virtual machine with your actual hdd?

VirtualBox can expose any physical drive or physical partition to a virtual machine as a virtual drive. You would need to put your HDD in a USB adaptor. You could then expose the new USB drive as a virtual drive for use in VirtualBox. BTW, VirtualBox is a free product which does not need to be registered or licensed.

I had no idea that you could do that in Virtualbox. I will need to look it up though.

You could ask a question or edit your existing question.

@GAP Of course Virtualbox can do it but NOT to boot from it like it seems to be your intention considering the newer question. Now, why exactly you want to boot that drive? If not encrypted you can access its contents from another computer and backup whatever PERSONAL files you need (others as well but for what purpose?).

I wanted to uninstall some software from my drive and even clone my drive.
